# multiple elements attached to one click event listener

Tags: javascript

what i want to happen is that on clicking one of the #playlist instances in the unordered list, it will take the corresponding instances inner text and use it to find the rest of the  information, like the csv and cover. this is what i have so far but im not sure if im going in the right direction or how to continue. thanks

```
const playlistCover = document.querySelector('#playlist-cover');
const playlistName = document.querySelector('#playlist-name');
const playlistDuration = document.querySelector('#playlist-duration');
const playlistLength = document.querySelector('#playlist-length');
const playlistSize = document.querySelector('#playlist-size');


const playlistSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.playlist #playlist').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        loadPlaylist();
    })
})

function loadPlaylist() {
    playlistName.innerText = playlist
    playlistCover.src = `static/playlists/${playlist}/cover.png`
    playlistCSV = `static/playlists/${playlist}/${playlist}.csv`
}
```

```
<div class="playlists">
    <h3>Playlists</h3>
    <ul>
        <li class="playlist">
            <a id="playlist" href="#hyperpop">hyperpop</a><a id="options">...</a>
        </li>

        <li class="playlist">
            <a id="playlist" href="#uk-rap">uk-rap</a><a id="options">...</a>
        </li>

        <li class="playlist">
            <a id="playlist" href="#misc">misc</a><a id="options">...</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="playlist-container">
        <div class="info">
            <div class="playlist-cover">
                <img src="static/playlists/uk-rap/cover.png" alt="playlist-cover" id="playlist-cover">
            </div>

            <div class="playlist-details">
                <div class="header">
                    <h1 id="playlist-name">uk-rap</h1>
                </div>

                <div id="playlist-data">
                    <p class="playlist-duration">6 hours 42 minutes</p>
                    <p class="playlist-songs">192 songs</p>
                    <p class="playlist-size">372.5 mb </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="static/scripts/playlist loader.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: You have multiple `id="playlist"`, which is not valid HTML.  Element `id`s _must_ be unique within a HTML document, and any JS operating on them (like your `document.querySelectorAll('.playlist #playlist')`) is not guaranteed to work, and will most likely pick up on the first matching element.  Use `class` instead of `id` when working with multiple elements.

Comment: ohhhh okay thanks ill try that

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of your code.

The way it works is by making the information hidden by default.

Then, when you click on the name of the playlist, the information appears.

This is handled by toggling the `hidden` class by using `elm.classList.toggle()`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".playlist .info")
  .forEach(p => p.parentElement.addEventListener(
    "click",
    () => p.classList.toggle("hidden"))
);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.playlist>span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="playlists">
    <li class="playlist">
      <span>UK-Rap</span>
      <div class="info hidden">
        <div class="duration">6 hours 42 mins</div>
        <div class="songs">192 songs</div>
        <div class="size">372.5 mb</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="playlist">
      <span>Jazz</span>
    </li>
    <li class="playlist">
      <span>Pop</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: wow thanks this will help a lot